# How to conditionally route to a component in react based on a variable in the route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Here is an abstract of the what I am trying to imply:

Existing route
`<Route path="/public/reports/:reportid/page/:pageid" component={ PageComponent}/>`

Idealist expectation of such a behaviour
`` <Route path="/public/reports/:reportid/page/:pageid" component={ `:pageid` === -1 ? IndexPage : PageCompoennt }/> ``

To render a pdf in headless browser I have defined a public route, as an addition an index page was added recently, though I have this common route for individual page download, I wanted to reuse the same for index page ( index page doesnt have an identifier, so I thought maybe i'll filter out using -1 to be its index..
The above code is the somewhat the ideal case Im looking for..
Is there a way like this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `render` prop of `Route`:

```
<Route 
    path="/public/reports/:reportid/page/:pageid" 
    render={(props) => 
        props.match.params.pageid === -1 ? 
            <IndexPage {...props} />: 
            <PageCompoennt {...props} />
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define your route like below

```
<Route path="/public/reports/:reportid/page/:pageid" component={ PageComponent}/>
```

and in your PageComponent you should use pageid for condition like below:

```
if(pageid===-1)
     return <YourFirstComponent />

return <YourSecondComponent />
```

now your your complexity is in your component, and its cleaner and more readable